# My Android app requires "Other" permissions in the Play Store - what does that mean and how to fix?

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I've just published (in Alpha) an SMS forwarding app in the Play Store.  When I click "Permissions: view details" it says "this app has access to: ? Other".  Why is that?  What can I do to fix it (so it still functions properly, as an SMS forwarder, but says something more useful than "? Other")?

Here are the permissions in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you added this feature : <uses-feature    android:name="android.hardware.telephony" ?

Comment: No - I'll add that, republish, and see what happens.

Comment: Did that, and it still says requires permission "? Other"

Answer (score 5):

**Other** is a permission group, not a permission in itself.  If nothing is listed under **? Other** and there's just the heading, then your app doesn't have any permissions that belong to the **Other** group.  If you do request permissions that belong to that group, then they will be listed under the **? Other** heading. Of the permissions you've listed, I think `WAKE_LOCK` is one of the **Other** permissions, so that's probably why you are seeing it.

Read all about the permission groups here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/6014972?hl=en.